# Using mongodb in standalone application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-webkit

I'm developing a Web Application with node-webkit who has including a Node.js server and MongoDB.

My Web Application starts, at the launching, the MongoDB daemon and the Node.js "server". So,I would like to know, if MongoDB is considered as embedded (does it mean that my project is under AGPL licence because of MongoDB ?) or the licence of MongoDB is not impacting the licence of my project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AGPL license do not apply to the soft who communicate whith the one under that license, in the case of database typically.[[agpl]](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html)

For example [pymongo is under the apache license](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/).

Comment: If I would like to sell my software, how can I integrate MongoDB ? Do I have to download and configure mongodb after the install of my software or can I give mongodb ?

Comment: It is an interisting question. I am not entirely sure, but I'll say that Microsoft sell lisence for Windows while they integrate free soft, do they ?